# Unpacking template parameters of a variadic templated class to constants and array of constants

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, unpack

I'm quite new to the variadic template of C++2011 and I would like to know if a trick exists to do the following thing :

```
template<typename T, unsigned int... TDIM> class VariadicTest
{
    public:
        static const unsigned int order_const = sizeof...(TDIM);
        static const unsigned int size_const = // TDIM1*TDIM2*TDIM3...
        static const unsigned int dim_const[order_const] = // {TDIM1, TDIM2, TDIM3...} 
                                                          // if not possible : 
                                                          // dim_const[64] = {TDIM1, TDIM2, TDIM3, 0, ..., 0}

};
```

Is there any "trick" to do a such thing ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: The `size_const` should be simple (create a `constexpr` variadic template function that returns the multiplication of the head times the tail --or the head value if no tail). The array initialization is the tricky part...

Comment: Actually, the syntax as proposed in the question would be invalid, as you cannot provide the value for a static array in the declaration of the member... that being said, the problem would be just as hard if the initialization is moved to the definition :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the way to implement other two functionality:

```
template<unsigned int... T> struct mul;
template<unsigned int L,unsigned int... T> struct mul<L,T...>
{
static const int val= L*mul<T...>::val;
};
template<unsigned int L> struct mul<L>
{
static const int val= L;
};

template<typename T, unsigned int... TDIM> class VariadicTest
{
    public:
        static const unsigned int order_const = sizeof...(TDIM);
        static const unsigned int size_const = mul<TDIM...>::val;
        static const unsigned int dim_const[order_const];
};
template<typename T, unsigned int... TDIM> 
const unsigned int VariadicTest<T,TDIM...>::dim_const[order_const] = {TDIM...};
```

Test : http://liveworkspace.org/code/cfb0ec09a05931cfcc00edf29866e716

Answer (score 1):

Here's a partial answer, it does `order_const` and `size_const`.  But I can't see how to do `dim_const` yet.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T, unsigned int... TDIM>
class VariadicTest;

template<typename T>
class VariadicTest<T>
{
    public:
        static const unsigned int order_const = sizeof...(TDIM);

        static const unsigned int size_const = 1;
};
template<typename T, unsigned int baseTDIM, unsigned int... others>
class VariadicTest<T, baseTDIM, others...>
{
    public:
        static const unsigned int order_const  = sizeof...(TDIM);
        static const unsigned int size_const = baseTDIM * VariadicTest<T,others...> :: size_const;    
};

int main() {
        VariadicTest<double, 9, 4, 5> x;
        cout << x.order_const << endl;
        cout << x.size_const << endl;
}
```

Comment: Uhm... isn't `order_const` already resolved in the question? (i.e. `sizeof...(TDIM)` should be transformed into the number of elements in the variadic part of the template.

Comment: In fact order_const is not a problem. The problem is for size_const and dim_const...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas, you're right.  I think I started doing that as an exercise to practice this recursive.  I'll put the `sizeof...` back in.